# Vectors, Classes, and Destructors

Tags: c++, class, vector

This is my class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    Base (int ind = 3)
    :m_ind(ind)
    {
        std::cout<<"Base ()"<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Base ()
    {
        std::cout<<"~Base ()"<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

I tried this code in main:

```
 Base(6)//literal base
```

- A "literal" base is created and compiler prints `"Base ()"`
- Since it is not a variable, just some memory when compiler moves out of it, it will delete an memory allocated to it
- compiler will print `"~Base ()"`

I tried running this code in main:

```
std::vector<Base>vec;
vec.push_back(Base(4));
```

what I expected was:

- Compiler creates `Base(4)` and stores it at `vec.at(0)`
- Constructor executed and `"Base ()"` is printed on screen
- when main function ends `"~Base ()"` is printed on screen

what I got:

- Compiler creates `Base(4)` and stores it at `vec.at(0)`
- Constructor executed and `"Base ()"` is printed on screen
- Compiler moves out of and Destructor is executed `"~Base ()"` is printed
- main function ends and `"~Base ()"` is printed

That means `Base(4)` is deleted when pushed inside vector, but how come that is possible if `vec.at(0)` is Base (it is inside the vector and haven't been deleted)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "literal base". Do you mean a temporary object of type `Base`?

Comment: Considering you have no `m_ind` member to be initialized, the code will not compile.

Comment: Copy-constructor is invoked, and you don't have any print statement for that case.

Comment: Please make your title describe the question rather than just naming language features. That will make it stand out in question lists and we will know what it is about.

Comment: You should try to clarify your understanding of the difference between "deleted" and "destroyed". The word "deleted" means something specific in C++, and you're using it incorrectly.

Comment: There's a terminology problem in your question - it's your compiled *program* that prints `Base ()` and `~Base ()`, not the compiler.  Similarly, it's the program that performs the rest of the actions you describe.  All the compiler does is build the program from your source code.

Comment: A similar question, where seemingly unmatched construction/destruction was seen when copy/move constructors were not instrumented: [Why CTOR is not called N times when I create a vector of N objects?](/q/42227766)

Comment: @Lightness Race in Orbit I am new at C++, yes an object of type base.

Comment: @Adam: Ok - a literal is something like `5` or `true` or `"hello world"`. An expression of a built-in type, directly stating its value.

Comment: @Toby Speight I am a C++ newbie. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: @Lightness Race in Orbit I thought Base(6) is a literal same as 5 (int literal). and an object is like a variable of type base.

Comment: @Adam: No, `Base(6)` is not a literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
vec.push_back(Base(4));
```

you create a *temporary* object. This temporary object is passed to the `push_back` function which *copies* or *moves* it into the vector (invoking a *copy constructor* or *move constructor* in your class). Then the `push_back` function returns and the temporary object is destructed.

Later when the vector itself is destructed, the copy inside the vector will be destructed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

You omitted to instrument the **copy constructor** of `Base`.  Although you didn't write one, the compiler provided a default one for you.  If you add a copy constructor, you will see that it is called (when copying the temporary `Base(4)` into the vector):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    Base(int)
    {
        std::cout<<"Base(int)"<<std::endl;
    }
    Base(const Base&)
    {
        std::cout<<"Base(Base)"<<std::endl;
    }

    virtual ~Base ()
    {
        std::cout<<"~Base()"<<std::endl;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<Base>vec;
    vec.push_back(Base(4));
}
```

This produces:

```
Base(int)
Base(Base)
~Base()
~Base()
```

If you use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`, you'll see that only one instance is constructed; it's not copied:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<Base>vec;
    vec.emplace_back(4);
}
```

```
Base(int)
~Base()
```